# WPF: Handling a touchmove event on another thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, event-handling

I'm writing a complex UI containing 1000 images, of which ~300 move following the user's touch (those who are nearest to the touch). To do this I have to compute the distance between the image and the touch point for every image, everytime that the handler is called. Unfortunately, when there is more than one user (we plan to use it on a big touch enabled TV) the application tends to lag. So my idea was to create a new thread for every touch and, inside the new thread, use the Application.Current.Dispatcher to update the UI:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
    //Update the UI
}));
```

Is that possible and/or is there a better way to do that?

Moreover: how can I handle the TouchMove event in another thread?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(some action)
```

does not invoke a separate thread, it executes the specified Action Asynchronously on the current thread, which is the UI thread in your case.

Look in to [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx). This invokes a separate thread that can be used to do your intensive calculations and has a `RunWorkerCompleted` callback to update the UI after your calculations are done.

Comment: Yes, I'm indeed using it inside the new thread to update back the UI, I'm editing the question to be more precise.

Comment: So.. your calculations take a long time and then the UI gets updated, though the UI thread is not frozen. Is that your problem?

Comment: Moreover I do not want to create a new BackgroundWorker or a new Thread inside the event callback, because doing so I would create a new Thread/ Object for every call. What I would like to do is to handle the TouchMove event enterely on a different thread.

Comment: Well then, either you need to optimize your calculations. may be you could cache some of them to avoid redundant calculations, or may be you could use a combination of some actual calculations and some hardcoded ones. I believe your hardware is limiting you.

Answer (score 1):

Bit's answer's great, and as a follow-up, here are a few possible ideas (besides caching) to speed up the process:

It seems surprising that it is the calculations of the distances, instead of moving the images, which causes the lag? I would imagine it's probably the latter - in which case, it might be worth looking at optimisations for your algorithm...

For example, the further away the other images from your touch, the less they move I imagine? Then you can maybe skip the movement more often for images further away:

Eg, give each image a lastUpdated DateTime, and the difference between that and the current time is `< CONST / distance` not update, say.

If this is still causing lag, or it is genuinely the calculation of the distances that is the problem, then perhaps the event is getting triggered too often, and you should put a check on the `TouchMove` event that the calculation hasn't been done too recently instead.

Just some thoughts :)

Comment: Well... it's probably moving the images the main problem, but as with that I've made all the possible optimizations I could find (which include what you said, limiting the event trigger frequency,  but also caching and lowering the quality of the images) I was trying to scrape the bottom of the barrel with other little optimizations here and there :) thank you for the answers!

Comment: Ahh cool, sorry for wasting you time! And best of luck with the optimisations! :)

Comment: You did not waste my time, you confirmed my strategy ;) thank you!